# Почему isdigit() не проверяет на наличие символа?

Tags: c++

Программа должна считывать числа пользователя, пока не `q`, отсортировать их и вывести в возрастающем порядке. Когда вводишь буквенный символ вместо цифры, программа падает. Для этого я проверяю, является ли запись в строке `digit` цифрой с помощью `isdigit()`, которая вернет `True`, если цифра и `0` - если не цифра. Я вроде прописал правильное условие, но после ввода цифры, программа все равно падает. Объясните, в чем я не разобрался?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector <int> v;
    string digit;
    int d;

    cout << "Enter digits: ";

    while (digit != "q") {
        getline(cin, digit);
        if (digit == "q") break;
        if (isdigit(stoi(digit)))
            d = stoi(digit);
        else{
            cout << "You entered a character.";
            break;
        }
        v.push_back(d);
    }

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (vector<int>::iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter)
        cout << *iter << ' ';
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `isdigit` работает с символами строки. В приведенном коде выполняется преобразован строки в число и проверка, является ли это число символом, соответствующим цифре. Т.е. здесь две ошибки: выполнение проверки уже **после** преобразования (`stoi`) и проверка не символов строки, а уже преобразованного числа.
Необходимо выполнять проверку содержимого введенной строки до попытки преобразования.
Можно также не использовать функцию `isdigit`, а перехватить исключение от функции `stoi`. Программа "падает" как раз потому, что генерируемое этой функцией (из-за неверной строки: с не-цифрами) исключение не перехватывается.

Answer (score -1):

Потому что если передать в `isdigit()` символ, то фактом в него упадет ASCII-код символа. 
И еще небольшой момент - `isdigit()` возвращает 0 или 1. Не помню как там в Си идет приведения 0/1 к булевому значению в условии. Лучше явно проверять на int.

Comment: Shamanic, а как это явно проверять на int?

Comment: if (isdigit(digit) == 1)

Comment: Shamanic, результат тот же.